# I need BASIC, HAND HOLDING type help booting Ubuntu now that I've installed it on my Windows 7 machine

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7

My son gave me an old desktop, maybe 4-5 years old, still in reasonably good shape, with Windows 7 installed.  It continually gives the "Windows is not Genuine" message and was/is infected with mucho malware/adware/viruses.  I have removed many of them, but decided to just start over with Ubuntu.  Now I've successfully installed it, or so I think.  I went through the setup process via a usb drive, was directed to reboot, and when I did so the old Windows boot came up.  I simply want to wipe the old OS and fully install Ubuntu.  Where did I go wrong?  Please remember, I'm not trained in software, hardware, etc., so if you are very technical at all then I'll have trouble following directions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu). This is a good starting point. In your case you should use the option to "Replace Windows […] with Ubuntu" during the installation process. If you have a particular question, please don't refrain to [open a new question](/questions/ask) and ping me, if you want to draw my attention to it. In general, the Q&A format of this site is not well suited to "hand-holding", though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Windows is still there. Here's what you can do:

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media (the same way you've done when you installed Ubuntu) and run the installer. When it asks about the disk partitioning, select  the "Erase disk and install" and proceed with the installation. When it finishes, you'll be prompted to reboot. Windows should be gone and Ubuntu should boot up.

Comment: OK, now I am opening the install file and it says "You are trying to open a hard disk image without a FAT or FAT32 partition".  Will that be fixed by the erase/install?